# Search for a string between two different delimiters in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database there are several text fields with content like this (spaces and so on are as they are in my database):

```
Phone:
    0 63 32/48 32 49
Mobile:
    04 78/9 62 83 74
Homepage:
    www.example.com
```

I need to change this to:

```
<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 63 32/48 32 49</dd>
<dt>Mobile:</dt><dd>04 78/9 62 83 74</dd>
<dt>Homepage:</dt><dd><a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a></dd>
```

I also googled but without success.

Does anybody know how to do that with SQL?

I would be very thankful for help.

Comment: you shouldn't do this with SQL you should do it with PHP. And you shouldn't save delimited data to the database in the first place.

Comment: But I need this done with SQL. Do you know how to do it with SQL?

Comment: Why does it need to be done in SQL?You could use a regex in PHP if this format is consistent.

Comment: That's the problem. Not all data are like this.

Comment: Provide the non standard examples. Also explain why it needs to  be done in SQL. I think doing this in SQL will be a lot of work (or the way I would do this in SQL would be a lot, perhaps someone has a better way).

Comment: Some are normal text. I need it done in SQL. It's hard to explain why, but I need to do it with SQL.

Comment: Okay, while i've removed the PHP tag for you. You should add some "normal text" example so someone could potentially help you. I think this will be a lot of work and require a stored procedure. Good luck. Also I don't see any delimiters.

Comment: This looks like someone 'obtained' a web scraping data dump and wants to put it into their own database. And I agree: the parsing should be done in PHP - and there are actually examples on the internet if the OP does a search.

Comment: No, these data are my own data. I'm actually moving from static HTML pages to dynamic with MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) can be used to split text into strings, and then strings can be wrapped in any required way:

```
Select Src,
  CONCAT('<dt>',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 1), Delim, -1),
    '</dt><dd>',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 2), Delim, -1),
    '</dd>
<dt>',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 3), Delim, -1),
    '</dt><dd>',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 4), Delim, -1),
    '</dd>
<dt>',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 5), Delim, -1),
    '</dt><dd><a href="http://',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 6), Delim, -1),
    '">',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 6), Delim, -1),
    '</a></dd>'
  ) As Tgt
From (
Select
'Phone:
    0 63 32/48 32 49
Mobile:
    04 78/9 62 83 74
Homepage:
    www.example.com' As Src, '
' As Delim) s0
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72687/0)

First sub-string can be just `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, 1),` and the last can be `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Src, Delim, -1)`, but I think it's clearer to have them in line with the rest.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. But I need for search for Phone, Mobile, Homepage…because it's not always the same order and number of item. Some only have a number, some have two home pages and some have multiple phone numbers, some even have an address.

Comment: Do you need to *search* for Phone, Mobile, Homepage etc. or accommodate for different formats? Do you need Address etc. of want to dump it?

Comment: What's the maximum number of tags per field?